# breakpoint does not hit in phpstorm+xdebug

Tags: xdebug, phpstorm

os: windows 7
web server: xampp 1.8.2 (php version: 5.4.27)
phpstorm: 6.0.3

in php.ini:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "D:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.4-5.4-vc9.dll"
;xdebug.default_enable=1 
;xdebug.auto_trace=1
;xdebug.show_exception_trace = 1  
;xdebug.collect_vars = 1 
;xdebug.collect_params=1
;xdebug.collect_return=1
;xdebug.profiler_append = 1
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "D:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 0
;xdebug.remote_autostart = off 
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "D:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.remote_mode = "req"
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
```

when I debug web application in phpstorm. xdebug is working but as same as running.
I have set some breakpoints, but it does not stop there.

Comment: I also want to set it in eclipse php 3.0.2. The result is same. I think there might be something wrong for php and xdebug.

Comment: *"xdebug.remote_enable = 0"* -- no wonder -- debugger is disabled. http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Xdebug+Installation+Guide

Comment: Thanks Lazyone, I made so stupid mistake this morning. remote_enable should be 1.

Comment: Have you configured the server paths?

Answer (score 2):

You have debugger disabled because of `xdebug.remote_enable = 0` config line.

It has to be `1` (on/true).

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Xdebug+Installation+Guide