# codeigniter phpstorm xdebug does not hit breakpoints in controller methods

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans, phpstorm, xdebug

I am using phpstorm 8.0.2, xampp 5.6.3 with codeigniter framework. I configured the php.ini file with the required settings. I think it does not have a problem since the phpstorm connects with xdebug and hit breakpoints in index.php. But if i keep a breakpoint in a code iginiter controller's function and navigate to the corresponding url (eg: index.php/controller/methodname) the break point does not hit. but the code works and the browser gets the output. I found several stackoverflow questions related to this (eg: [breakpoint does not hit in phpstorm+xdebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068091/breakpoint-does-not-hit-in-phpstormxdebug)). but those solutions did not work.

I tried netbeans as well but got the same result.

Comment: The debugger is not active when you got to that URL.

Comment: What did u mean? It hits breakpoints in index.php and I can 'step into' as well.

Comment: And can you step through to the other breakpoint manually?

Comment: any suggestion to verify that and fix the issue?

Comment: That's why I ask. Can you step through to the other breakpoint manually? Do you come across it when you stop at each individual line of code? It's just that a) the line with the breakpoint is not executed or b) it's a line where you can't set a breakpoint. Stepping through would show you that.

Comment: @hakre I can step through to the other files too. But I didn't try to step until the controller.

Comment: Try that. It should give you more clarification. Place other breakpoints as well, so you come closer first which should be faster.

Comment: @hakre I ll try and post

Comment: Please provide an xdebug log for such debug session: http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log Right now it sounds like path mappings are missing or incorrect.

Comment: this is an xdebug.log i could generate previously. but i was unable to generate one again.https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9zhpr7PNtIDZGRYYThfNG93MXM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: From what I see it looks like it tries to stop at `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/techask/application/controllers/Auth.php` file at line no 3 (your breakpoint is on line 11). Is that a correct path (I mean -- the same as shown in PhpStorm, including letter case)? What sort of line is that? xdebug sometime is unable to hit breakpoint due to the way how PHP generates byte code. Try setting it (breakpoint) on simple (single) lines. What will happen if you do programmatic breakpoint: add `xdebug_break();` in your code -- will it stop there? Xdebug version?

Comment: Please also attach the header and xdebug part from `phpinfo();` output (must be run in the same environment as your debug attempts, e.g. via web browser).

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9zhpr7PNtIDWlpQTXBCYVFLTVE/view?usp=sharing this is the phpinfo(). i attached the whole info. the path u asked is correct and the line was a load view '$this->load->view()'. I ll try xdebug_break(); and post.

Comment: it breaks on xdebug_break();

Comment: 1) `Run | Break at first line in PHP scripts` -- try activating/deactivating this option few times -- sometimes it stuck and shows wrong status. The final status should be "inactive" 2) Try upgrading xdebug from your 2.2.3 to 2.2.5 -- one of the older xdebug version sometimes starts ignoring breakpoints at all (don't remember exact version and exact description.. but faced in myself 2 times -- maybe it's a similar case).

Comment: 3) Maybe delete your entries at "Preferences | PHP | Servers" and follow this zero-config article so that IDE will help recreating it (in case if it has anything to do with it): http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm

Comment: @LazyOne 'Run | Break at first line in PHP scripts' this one dint work. should try updating xdebug as the last choice.

Comment: Did you solved this problem? I'm having the same issue. Thanks